# Error when connecting to SFTP server using Python Pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am executing a Python script on my Linux server that uses pysftp to connect to another server in order to read files that are sitting in a directory of that remote server. When I run the script, it fails out while connecting to the remote server and creates a text file with the title: 'This service allows sftp connections only.'

This file is created inside my project directory. Below is the part of my code that is failing:

```
def sftp_get_file(sftp_host, sftp_username):
    with pysftp.Connection(sftp_host, sftp_username) as sftp:
        # transfer file from remote to local
        sftp.get(remote_file, local_file)
```

Code is very simple and works when I've tested it using my local server as the remote server. When I tested it in the new environment by actually depending on SFTP, then it failed. Any suggestions? Is pysftp using SSH at some point when it should be using only SFTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was due to me performing sftp.execute('ls') a couple lines down in the script. The server I was remoting onto only supported sftp commands and that command was forbidden.